# How to Display List of Classes and it properties in a propertygrid that implement an interface C#

Tags: c#, class, interface, propertygrid

I have a property grid that display the properties of the class (let's call it MyClass)

I want to have a property in MyClass that will contain all the classes that implement interface (let's called it ISomething) and will be represented in the PropertyGrid as drop down list ( same behavior when you have an enum)

Next when selecting one of the classes in the list will get all the properties of the selected class and appears in the propertyGrid

I did some readings and found some partial solution of how to get all the classes list and create an instances of it, but not sure how to use this instances to create a list of classes in the property grid.

```
var instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISomething))
                     && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
            select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as ISomething;

foreach (var instance in instances)
{
instance.Foo(); // where Foo is a method of ISomething
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: This code is not relevant to the property grid. What have you tried in the property grid area?

Comment: I didn't implement it to the grid yet, you are right this won't work

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/):

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<Something>();
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<Something2>();

var instances = kernal.GetAll<ISomething>();
foreach (var instance in instances)
{
    instance.Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return the `List` of objects and each object will have class name and the `List` of property names:

```
var classesWithProperties = 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISomething)) && t.IsClass)
            .Select(c => new { ClassName = c.FullName, Properties = c.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name)})
            .ToList();
```

Then you can iterate by this collections and display it as you wish.

Comment: so after I go through each object in classesWithProperties how I will show of a collection of classes list and each class it property and property values. it is not returning a list of properties. Also Im assuming in you code Ilist is the Isomething in my case

Comment: here what i did so far Dictionary<string, ISomthing> classObject = new Dictionary<string, ICamera>(); after i call ur code i do foreach (var field in classesWithProperties)
            {
                classObject.Add(field.ClassName, field.Properties as ISomething);
            }     when I call the propertygrid call the property with the dictinary list I get name correct by on the other side i get the ISomthing->Value->Key and Value filed with nothing in value

Comment: Value will be empty, because to display the values you need to have an instances of objects. Even if you will use `Activator` to create the objects - properties will have the default values (what I guess doesn't make any sense).

Comment: you are right I need to create an instance of the object to get the default value

Comment: So, you don't need the list of properties. You just need the list of object - need to you `Activator` to create them. But there might be a problem if this classes don't have a default constructor.